# Problemas de lentidão com AJAX no ASP .NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou com um problema de lentidão na resposta do meu AJAX. Utilizo o seguinte código para fazer a busca e retornar uma lista de resultados:

Javascript

```
function enviaBusca(url) {
    var resultado = $('#resultados'),
        mensagem = $('#mensagem'),
        palavras = $('input[type=hidden][name=palavrasTemp]').val(),
        palavraChave = $('#txt_palavra_chave').val(),
        valorMinimo = $('input[type=number][name=valor_minimo]').val(),
        valorMaximo = $('input[type=number][name=valor_maximo]').val(),
        buscaPublicado = $('')
    param = { 'buscaTermo': encodeURIComponent(palavraChave), 'palavrasBuscadas': palavras, 'buscaTipoImovel': get_lista_tipos_marcados(), 'buscaEstado': get_lista_estados_marcados(), 'buscaCidade': get_lista_cidades_marcadas(), 'buscaBairro': get_lista_bairros_marcados(), 'buscaCaptador': get_lista_captadores_marcados(), 'buscaPretensao': get_lista_pretensoes_marcadas(), 'buscaFinalidade': get_lista_finalidades_marcadas(), 'buscaSituacao': get_lista_situacoes_marcadas(), 'buscaValorMinimo': valorMinimo, 'buscaValorMaximo': valorMaximo, 'buscaPublicado': get_lista_publicados_marcadas() };

    $('#loading').removeClass('invisivel');
    resultado.empty();
    mensagem.addClass('invisivel');

    $.post(url, add_anti_forgery_token(param), function (response) {
        if (response) {
            if (response.length > 0) {
                resultado.removeClass('invisivel');
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    resultado.html(response);
                }
            }
        } else {
            resultado.addClass('invisivel');
            mensagem.html('Nenhum resultado foi encontrado com os filtros selecionados.').removeClass('invisivel');
        }
        $('#loading').addClass('invisivel');
    });
}
```

Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Resultados(string buscaTermo, string palavrasBuscadas, List<int> buscaTipoImovel, List<int> buscaEstado, List<int> buscaCidade, List<int> buscaBairro, List<int> buscaCaptador, List<int> buscaPretensao, List<int> buscaFinalidade, List<int> buscaSituacao, int buscaValorMinimo, int buscaValorMaximo, List<int> buscaPublicado)
         {
            var palavrasTemp = palavrasBuscadas;
            if (palavrasTemp != "")
            {
                palavrasChave.Add(palavrasTemp);
            }
            palavrasChave.Add(buscaTermo);

            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                buscaSituacao.Clear();
                buscaSituacao.Add(1);
                buscaPublicado.Clear();
                buscaPublicado.Add(1);
            }

            var lista = ImoveisModel.RecuperarListaBusca(palavrasChave, buscaTipoImovel, buscaEstado, buscaCidade, buscaBairro, buscaCaptador, buscaPretensao, buscaFinalidade, buscaSituacao, buscaValorMinimo, buscaValorMaximo, buscaPublicado);
            ViewBag.TermoBuscado = palavrasChave;
            ViewBag.ListaImoveis = lista;
            ViewBag.QuantidadeRegistrosEncontrados = lista.Count();
            return PartialView(lista);
        }
```

JSON enviado

```
param = { 'buscaTermo': encodeURIComponent(palavraChave), 'palavrasBuscadas': palavras, 'buscaTipoImovel': get_lista_tipos_marcados(), 'buscaEstado': get_lista_estados_marcados(), 'buscaCidade': get_lista_cidades_marcadas(), 'buscaBairro': get_lista_bairros_marcados(), 'buscaCaptador': get_lista_captadores_marcados(), 'buscaPretensao': get_lista_pretensoes_marcadas(), 'buscaFinalidade': get_lista_finalidades_marcadas(), 'buscaSituacao': get_lista_situacoes_marcadas(), 'buscaValorMinimo': valorMinimo, 'buscaValorMaximo': valorMaximo, 'buscaPublicado': get_lista_publicados_marcadas() }
```

A consulta roda até que rápido, o tempo varia de 20 a 600ms dependendo da quantidade de resultados obtidos mas o problema é o retorno do AJAX, leva alguns minutos para montar a tela e esconder a div loading ... O que pode ter de errado?

Comment: Bem vindo Cristiano. Você checou se o problema não está no loop do response? Não parece necessário esse loop, não sei oque tem no response, mas independente do tamanho ele está substituindo o html N vezes mas sempre pelo mesmo valor (response).

Comment: Então George, o loop é exatamente para preencher a lista de resultados (neste caso lista de imóveis encontrados com os filtros). Com poucos resultados até retorna rápido mas a partir de 10 resultados leva muito tempo para retornar, até congela a tela impedindo a navegação ou seleção de outros filtros para a busca.

Comment: Ficaria mais fácil conseguir ajuda se você postar o código da controller também e dar um exemplo de como é o retorno. Mas avalie se a resposta abaixo já não atende suas necessidades.

Comment: Adicionei o código do Controller, como disse ao amigo abaixo o meu retorno é uma List<ImoveisModel>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depois de quebrar bastante a cabeça tentando achar o problema no AJAX eu parei e pensei no óbvio: qual o retorno? É uma lista, sendo uma lista não preciso percorrer o objeto "response" para montar uma lista então resolvi removendo o for e deixando assim:

Código antigo

```
$.post(url, add_anti_forgery_token(param), function (response) {
    if (response) {
        if (response.length > 0) {
            resultado.removeClass('invisivel');
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                resultado.html(response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        resultado.addClass('invisivel');
        mensagem.html('Nenhum resultado foi encontrado com os filtros selecionados.').removeClass('invisivel');
    }
    $('#loading').addClass('invisivel');
});
```

Código novo

```
$.post(url, add_anti_forgery_token(param), function (response) {
    if (response.length > 0) {
        resultado.removeClass('invisivel');
        resultado.html(response);
    } else {
        resultado.addClass('invisivel');
        mensagem.html('Nenhum resultado foi encontrado com os filtros selecionados.').removeClass('invisivel');
    }
    $('#loading').addClass('invisivel');
});
```

Obrigado a todos pelas respostas e deixo aqui a solução para que se alguém mais tiver problemas parecidos possa resolver.

Comment: É exatamente oque comentei pra você la na sua pergunta. hehehe
Que bom que achou a solução! :)

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que estou vendo a consulta não te retorna apenas um JSON, mas todo o HTML já propriamente formatado. Quando você disse que a consulta era rápida, isso inclui a formatação do HTML, ou só a consulta no banco de dados?

Formatar strings da maneira errada pode ser muito custoso. Strings geralmente são imutáveis, o que significa que ao se concatenar 2 strings, o compilador precisa realocar toda a memória da variável.

Em C#, a forma correta de se construir longas strings, é com o objeto StringBuilder.

Se você já está fazendo isso no seu servidor, e a lentidão é toda do JavaScript, não há muito o que fazer, recomendo você substituir o

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    resultado.html(response);
}
```

por

```
resultado.html(response.join(''));
```

Comment: Na realidade o meu retorno é uma List<Imovel>, ai no resultados.cshtml eu monto o html. Quando me referi ao tempo de carregamento é justamente o model retornado pelo JSON.

Comment: Já trabalhei com tabelas que eram grandes demais para serem renderizadas de uma só vez. Quando você chega a esse ponto o melhor a se fazer é renderizar 50-100 itens de cada vez, e colocar um eventListener no scroll da window para renderizar mais itens quando o usuário rolar a barra de navegação até o final.

Comment: Entendo, mas neste caso não acredito ser problema com a quantidade de registros pois mesmo uma consulta que retorne 10 registros demora uns 5 minutos para completar, isso quando não dá timeout. Eu tenho uma lista que traz todos os imóveis registrados que não usa AJAX e carrega rapidinho. Na busca preciso do AJAX para que o usuário aplique filtros para diminuir a lista sem ter que ficar trocando de página toda hora.

Comment: Mas então você está usando AJAX apenas para filtrar os resultados de uma lista que você já tem em tela? Não seria melhor usar JavaScript para filtrar esses resultados?

Comment: Não é bem isso, acho que não ajudou minha resposta. O que eu disse sobre ter uma lista é em outra sessão do site, na busca eu carrego os filtros e a partir do momento em que eu seleciono o primeiro filtro eu carrego a primeira lista. A partir dai a cada interação do usuário com os filtros (click em um checkbox) a consulta AJAX é feita novamente aplicando o filtro selecionado. Adicionei na resposta o JSON que envio para o Model.